# Using variable of run_query in a DBT model

Tags: if-statement, variables, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jinja2, dbt

I'm using Dbt - Snowflake to insert values in a table. The model I create must behave differently depending on whether I'm on the weekend or not. During the week we do Append and during the weekend we do Truncate. To do this I check the current date with a "run_query" and I test the return value in an if tag. However I have a behavior that does not correspond to what I am looking for.

```
{% set boolWeek = run_query(select IFF(DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE()) in ('Sat', 'Sun'), 'True','False'))%}

  {% if  boolWeek == 'True' %}

    {{ config({
    "query_tag":"Test",
    "alias":"Test",
    "materialized":"table",
    "schema":"HUB"
       })
     }}
  {% else %}

    {{ config({
    "query_tag":"Test",
    "alias":"Test",
    "materialized":"incremental",
    "schema":"HUB"
       })
     }}
  {% endif %}
```

I've tried several form of settings for the variable and several form of its reference (`"{{boolWeek}}"`, `boolWeek.columns[0].values()` etc.) no one works.

I'm quite lost and would like some examples to figure it properly out.

Comment: What does `{{ boolWeek | pprint }}` gives you?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You would need to wrap your SQL within `run_query()` in quotes, such as it looks like this:

```
{% set boolWeek = run_query("select IFF(DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE()) in ('Sat', 'Sun'), 'True','False')")%}
```

2. (bonus, not needed to run this) If you are dealing with booleans, why not use them instead of strings? You could change your SQL to look like this to accomplish so:

```sql
select coalesce(dayname(current_date()) in ('Sat', 'Sun'), false)
```

3. (bonus, related to the latter bullet) If you then use booleans, you would need to adjust your Jinja `if` statement:

`{% if boolWeek == true %}`

So, the whole thing would look like this:

```
{% set boolWeek = run_query("select coalesce(dayname(current_date()) in ('Sat', 'Sun'), false)") %}

  {% if boolWeek == true %}

    {{ config({
    "query_tag":"Test",
    "alias":"Test",
    "materialized":"table",
    "schema":"HUB"
       })
     }}

  {% else %}

    {{ config({
    "query_tag":"Test",
    "alias":"Test",
    "materialized":"incremental",
    "schema":"HUB"
       })
     }}

  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Double bonus for point #2 - Why use `coalesce`? `select dayname(current_date()) in ('Sat', 'Sun');` works just fine ;)

Comment: Completely valid, yes! That’s just me being overly cautious